# Не умещаются "%" в круговой диаграмме google charts

Tags: php, javascript, css

Есть диаграммы , построенны с помощью google charts . По умолчанию у они не отображаются(т.е display: none) , при клике на кнопку они появляются , но в таком вот виде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проценты смещаются вправо . В чем может дело ? когда отображаю сразу без клика , то все нормально .

Comment: все дело в карме

Comment: до последнего момента надеялся , что нет

Comment: ну тогда стоит добавить код, чтобы кто-то мог помочь Вам)